# Callback on notifyiteminserted / notifyitemremoved / notifyitemmoved

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview

Looking for something really simple. I looked around in the source code for `RecyclerView` but couldn't find anything for this. Before I start implementing my own version, I wanted to know if someone knows of anyway to receive a callback on the animation for `notifyiteminserted`, `notifyitemremoved`, `notifyitemmoved`?

This is important because I want to know when the animation has completed.

Comment: Hey AndyRoid. Did you come to any conclusion for this?

Comment: Same question as @Ryan. Would like to know this too