# CoordinatorLayout/AppBarLayout interfere with RecyclerView scrollToPosition(bottom scrolling)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

This question has been asked many times but it just doesn't seem to have a solution that fits my requirement.

I have a Recipe that has instructions. Each instruction is ordered in a `RecyclerView`. The order must be from top to bottom. It cannot be reversed like many answers to this question.

I have an Add button that when clicked a new item is added at the bottom of the list. I need to scroll to the new item after the insert. So I employed the following code in the button's `onClick` event:

```
mRecyclerAdapter.addItem(newInstruction);
mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(mRecyclerAdapter.getItemCount() - 1);
```

This scrolls to the second last item because in the adapter's **addItem()** method I have this:

```
mItems.add(item);
notifyItemInserted(getItemCount() - 1);
```

I don't know the details of the `notifyItemInserted()` call, but it appears to be on a separate thread, which means that `smoothScrollToPosition()` is called before the views have been laid out after the insertion. Hence, it only scrolls to the second last item.

I have tried looking for a "callback" function along the lines of `onItemInserted` but I did not have any luck. eg, no answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34350970/callback-on-notifyiteminserted-notifyitemremoved-notifyitemmoved).

How do I solve this problem?

***EDIT START***

I've simplified the code in a new project in hope to find the problem, and found out what the problem is. It appears to be a problem caused by CoordinatorLayout/AppBarLayout when scrolling flag is enabled. It seems as though the scrolling did not take into consideration the extra scrolling space added by the AppBarLayout.

In the sample codes below, if you disable the scrolling flag for the app bar, scrolling to the bottom of the screen works perfectly as intended. However, if you enable the AppBarLayout scrolling behavior, and change its height, you'll notice that scrolling to the bottom is off by the given height.

I need the scrolling behavior, so how do I make them play nicely with each other? Please note that I've changed the question to reflect the problem.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    public static final int ITEMS_COUNT = 50;

    private FloatingActionButton mFloatingActionButton;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerAdapter mRecyclerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mFloatingActionButton = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fabButton);
        mFloatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        setupRecyclerView();
    }

    private void setupRecyclerView() {
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        mRecyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(createItemList());
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mRecyclerAdapter);
    }

    private List<String> createItemList() {
        List<String> itemList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < ITEMS_COUNT; i++) {
                itemList.add("Item " + i);
            }
        return itemList;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(49);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <!-- changing the height affects the scrolling distance -->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="Header"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/> <!--   this is the problem -->

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**RecyclerAdapter.java**

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private List<String> mItemList;

    public RecyclerAdapter(List<String> itemList) {
        mItemList = itemList;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Context context = parent.getContext();
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.recycler_item, parent, false);
        return RecyclerItemViewHolder.newInstance(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        RecyclerItemViewHolder holder = (RecyclerItemViewHolder) viewHolder;
        String itemText = mItemList.get(position);
        holder.setItemText(itemText);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mItemList == null ? 0 : mItemList.size();
    }

}
```

**recycler_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                                    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="8dp"
        style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**EDIT END**

Comment: What is the order of your call .I think notifyItemInserted(getItemCount() - 1); should be called first and  after that call smoothScrollToPosition to with a small delay.

Comment: Did you get any solution. Please let me know it would be helpful for us. I'm also facing same issue here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing a bit more research I found this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38073272/recyclerlayout-inside-coordinatorlayout-scrolltoposition-visibility) which has a workaround to this problem. Although not ideal, it will have to do for now. Though the real solution shouldn't have to collapse the AppBarLayout, the scrolling should take into consideration the extra scrolling space needed. Perhaps this is just a bug that is overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

In your **addItem()** method change this

```
notifyItemInserted(getItemCount() - 1);
```

to

```
notifyItemInserted(mItems.size() - 1);
```

This will solve the problem!

Comment: That's the exact same thing. getItemCount returns mItems.size()

Comment: @chaser Ya that's right! my bad. Can you post your adapter's code?

Comment: posted. and the problem is related to the appbarlayout, though I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

add this after adding item

```
    notifyItemRangeChanged(0, items.size());
```

Comment: This is the same thing as notifyItemInserted(getItemCount() - 1);

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(mRecyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount());
```

You can also put it in a runnable like this to make sure item has added before you scroll to it.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(mRecyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount());
            }
        }, 1000);
```

Comment: Interestingly, even with the Runnable, I would think that the delay would allow the RecyclerView to scroll to the end... It's still doing the same thing. I don't understand. I've made sure that the item count is the last item. I've even debugged it and it is definitely the last item. I will simplify my code and post it for others to test. What the heck is wrong with this scolling bs...

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code too, problem is there somewhere, just you need to look hard :)

Comment: I did more testing! I added 20 items at the start of my activity, and I changed the add button to scroll to a specific position manually. When I'm at the bottom of the page I pressed the button and what do you know, it scrolled to the top of the list just fine. Similarly, with any other number, as long as the scrolling goes to the top. However, as soon as the scrolling needs to go downward, it only shows the 1/4 of the previous item. For example if I want to scroll down to item 10, I only see a quarter of item 9. So it's not a problem of position, it's a problem of scrolling offset or somethin

Comment: @chaser try [Reversing](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#setReverseLayout(boolean)) the layout, I think this might work?

Comment: Nope, doesn't resolve the issue. I'll post the codes. See if you can replicate.

Comment: I found out what the problem is, if recyclerview is used in conjunction with coordinator/appbarlayout, scrollToPosition will be off because of the extra scrolling added for the appbar. So far I haven't found a solution to the problem though.

Answer (score 0):

Before you add list to adapter in Recycleview do some sorting by using Collection method according to your need,use this code may help you

```
Comparator<Long> comparator = Collections.reverseOrder();
Collections.sort(arrayList, comparator);
```